# How to quickly view a jupyter notebook on a Mac

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to quickly view a jupyter notebook without opening python and a web browser?  (Using a text editor is messy.)

Comment: What is the OS you use? If macOS, just click on file and press space bar. it will preview the file. if not macOS, hope someone here will help you. :)

Comment: Mac quick view just shows an app not the file itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nbconvert` and create the type of document of your preference (for example PDF with the help of LaTeX installation) ([examples](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). Also, if you use Visual Studio Code, there is a [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jithurjacob.nbpreviewer).

Answer (score 0):

For **Mac OS** users.

There is an Automator script can open it with just right-clicking the file and select **Convert to `html` (or `py`, `txt`)** in Quick Actions.

And then preview or open it.

BTW, it can also open `ipynb` file directly.

[Github link](https://github.com/JunsW/FastJN)

[image]